# pandas split cumsum to upper limits and then continue with remainder in different column

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a `DataFrame` such that:

```
            Amt 
Date  
01/01/2000  10    
01/02/2000  10    
01/03/2000  10    
01/04/2000  10    
01/05/2000  10    
01/06/2000  10    
01/07/2000  10
```

Now suppose I have two storage facilities to store the `Amt` of product that I purchase; **Storage 1** which has a cap of 22.5, and **Storage 2** which has a capacity of 30. I  would like to add both of these as columns and have them each sum cumulatively at a **SPLIT** quantity of `Amt`  (for every 10, 5 goes into each). Once **Storage 1** reaches capacity, I would like the remainder to go into **Storage 2** until it becomes full, at which point the remainder would go into a *third* column, **Sell**. After this, the `Amt` can continue to accumulate in the **Sell** column for the remainder of the `DataFrame`, such that the output would look like:

```
            Amt | Storage 1 | Storage 2 | Sell |
Date  
01/01/2000  10    5           5           0
01/02/2000  10    10          10          0
01/03/2000  10    15          15          0
01/04/2000  10    20          20          0
01/05/2000  10    22.5        27.5        0
01/06/2000  10    22.5        30          7.5
01/07/2000  10    22.5        30          17.5
```

I am aware of `cumsum` but I am not sure how to set conditions on it, nor do I know how to retrieve the remainder value in the case the storage fills up.

I apologize if this is unclear. If I am missing any necessary information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `Amt` always `10` ?

Comment: @AndyL. I should have clarified. It will always be the same in the dataframe, but the dataframe is dynamic. So for example it might be a different value, but the value for every row would be the same. Is that clear or do I sound stupid?

Comment: In that case, the solution is simple. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all values in `Amt` are the same, You may create each column by using `cumsum` and `clip` as follows

```
s = df.Amt.cumsum()
df['Storage 1'] = (s/2).clip(upper=22.5)
df['Storage 2'] = (s - df['Storage 1']).clip(upper=30)
df['sell'] = s - df['Storage 1'] - df['Storage 2']

Out[556]:
            Amt  Storage 1  Storage 2  sell
Date
01/01/2000   10        5.0        5.0   0.0
01/02/2000   10       10.0       10.0   0.0
01/03/2000   10       15.0       15.0   0.0
01/04/2000   10       20.0       20.0   0.0
01/05/2000   10       22.5       27.5   0.0
01/06/2000   10       22.5       30.0   7.5
01/07/2000   10       22.5       30.0  17.5
```

Comment: If I may ask, what would be the benefit of this solution over Henry's? I'm not sure I know enough to adequately discern what would be more 'pythonic'

Comment: @poorpractice: in Henry's solution, values to check on conditions in `np.select`  are depended on your upper values. If you change upper values from  `22.5` and `30` to something else. You need to change all 4 values(22.5, 30, 45, 52.5) in that solution. In mine, you only need to change upper values(22.5, 30)

Comment: @poorpractice: just for further clarification. I never say one solution is better than the other. Besides, Henry's solution with minor adjustment would be depended on only upper values(22.5, 30) as mine. It is up to you to feel comfortable to use either one.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean it in a contest sense, sorry if it came out that way. I just don't know enough to discern. What about in the event where I would like the sale column to just populate the volume for THAT day; so it would be the remainder for that day where it spills over, and then every day after that it would just be the amount?

Comment: @poorpractice: your description of the issue in the comment is kind of vague. It is hard to visualize it. Could you post a new question for it with detail explanation and sample and desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.select` to get the storage amount:

```
s = df["Amt"].cumsum()

df["Storage 1"] = np.select([s<=45, s>45],
                            [s/2,22.5])
df["Storage 2"] = np.select([s<=52.5, s>52.5],
                            [s-df["Storage 1"], 30])

df["Sell"] = s-df["Storage 1"]-df["Storage 2"]

print (df)
#

            Amt  Storage 1  Storage 2  Sell
Date
01/01/2000   10        5.0        5.0   0.0
01/02/2000   10       10.0       10.0   0.0
01/03/2000   10       15.0       15.0   0.0
01/04/2000   10       20.0       20.0   0.0
01/05/2000   10       22.5       27.5   0.0
01/06/2000   10       22.5       30.0   7.5
01/07/2000   10       22.5       30.0  17.5
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for this. I will try this when I get into work today and respond accordingly!

Comment: If I may, what is the advantage of this over Andy's solution, or vice versa?